# IBOutlet control is nil

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to set text of a NSTextField from a different class..

This is what i have:

Preferences.h

```
@interface Preferences : NSObject
{
IBOutlet NSTextField *selectionPointX;
}
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextField *dateTimeFormatPreview;

- (void)getSelection:(NSPoint)point :(NSSize)size;

@end
```

Preferences.m (only what's needed)

```
#import "Preferences.h"

@implementation Preferences

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = nil;

int cPx;
int cPy;
int cSw;
int cSh;

- (void)getSelection:(NSPoint)point :(NSSize)size{
    cPx = (int) point.x;
    cPy = (int) point.y;
    cSw = (int) size.width;
    cSh = (int) size.height;
    [self saveSelection];
}

- (void)saveSelection{
    NSPoint p;
    p.x = cPx;
    p.y = cPy;

    NSSize s;
    s.width = cSw;
    s.height = cSh;

    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromPoint(p) forKey:@"selectionPoint"];
        NSLog(@"Saved Window Position: X: %i Y: %i", cPx, cPy);

    [userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromSize(s) forKey:@"selectionSize"];
        NSLog(@"Saved Window Size: W: %i H: %i", cSw, cSh);
    [userDefaults synchronize];


    [selectionPointX setIntegerValue:cPx]; // selectionPointX is nil
}

@end
```

I call `getSelection` from a different class, passing values to it.

In the Interface Builder, i have a NSObject with class `Preferences`, and from it i have connected the Outlet to the controller.
But when debugging `selectionPointX` is `nil` and so not updating my TextField.

I'm new to objective-c so probably i'm doing it wrong.
I have searched a lot but can't find a solution.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

---

**EDIT:** I think i have found the problem. Since i call the method from a different class, i create another instance of that class, and so all connections are not hooked up.

I did that:

```
Preferences *prefs = [[Preferences alloc] init];
[prefs getSelection:(NSPoint)wPos :(NSSize)wSize];
```

**How i can call the same method, but using the current instance of `Preferences` that is loaded by the XIB?**

Answer (score 0):

I have a LocalSettingsController which is similiar to what you want here. In order to use the same Preferences instance all the time implement the Singleton pattern. Here's the code:

```
@implementation LocalSettingsController

+ (id)alloc
{
    return self.sharedSettings;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone: (NSZone *)zone
{
    return self.sharedSettings;
}

+ (instancetype)sharedSettings
{
    static LocalSettingsController* singleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singleton = [[self localAlloc] localInit];
    });

    return singleton;
}

- (id)init
{
    return self;
}

+ (id)localAlloc
{
    return [super allocWithZone: NULL];
}

- (id)localInit
{
    return [super init];
}
```

In code you can use the `sharedSettings` member, in IB you'd place an NSObject in your xib and change its instance type to LocalSettingsController (or in your case Preferences).